# How can I view last installed package or program?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

Can user list last installed packages by `apt-get` in terminal?

I need to know which last package I installed on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See `/var/log/dpkg.log`. Or do ...

```
less /var/log/dpkg.log
```

It will list all activity regarding packages.

More specific to installation:

```
grep installed /var/log/dpkg.log
```

It will list it like this:

```
2014-01-02 11:20:07 status half-installed libmodule-pluggable-perl 3.6-1
2014-01-02 11:20:07 status half-installed libemail-simple-perl 2.003-1
2014-01-02 11:20:07 status half-installed libemail-abstract-perl 2.134-1
2014-01-02 11:20:07 status half-installed libtime-piece-perl 1.11-2
2014-01-02 11:20:07 status half-installed libemail-date-perl 1.102-1
2014-01-02 11:20:07 status half-installed libmime-lite-perl 3.020-2ubuntu2
2014-01-02 11:20:08 status installed libmodule-pluggable-perl 3.6-1
2014-01-02 11:20:08 status installed libemail-simple-perl 2.003-1
2014-01-02 11:20:08 status installed libemail-abstract-perl 2.134-1
2014-01-02 11:20:08 status installed libtime-piece-perl 1.11-2
2014-01-02 11:20:08 status installed libemail-date-perl 1.102-1
2014-01-02 11:20:08 status installed libmime-lite-perl 3.020-2ubuntu2
```

Answer (score 2):

Rinzwind answered the question well above. If you want to use a GUI, open Synaptic by opening the Ubuntu Dash and typing "Synaptic". You will be prompted for your root password.

When Synaptic is open, go to File --> History. Then select the most recent month and day, and you will be presented with a list of installed, upgraded and removed packages on that day.